# Vim Saving Macro to File. Encoding Issue

Tags: windows, macros, editor, vim

I'm trying to save a macro to the file I'm editing.

All goes well until I close and reopen the file. When I reopen the file, the pasted macro

```
<80><fc>^B Setup^M<80>
```

has become

```
■üSetup^M■
```

I assume this is encoding related but it's beyond me on how to resolve it.

Following are some settings that might be relevant:

- fileformat=dos
- fileformats=dos,unix
- fileencoding=latin1
- fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
- encoding=utf-8

Does anyone have an idea what I need to change to *make it work*?

### Edit

I had no idea where the `<80><fc>^B` sequence was coming from.

It appears to be inserted into the macro when I type `//***** Setup` with the `SHIFT` key pressed up until the S from setup. The macro gets pasted as `//*****<80><fc>^B Setup`

*Note 1: I use an Azerty keyboard. For the keys `/` and `*`, I need to press the shift key.*

*Note 2: A solution is to not hold the `SHIFT` key when typing the `space` character between `//*****` and `Setup`. Holding the shift key mearly has become an automatism when typing that pretty much used sequence.*

Comment: Try to reproduce this starting with `vim -u NONE`.

Comment: @ZyX - the pasted macro is now immediatly ■üSetup^M■. I do hope that tells you something (it doesn't to me).

Comment: It should tell me whether this is plugin related. How do you paste your macro with `vim -u NONE` (starting from where you copied it)? You should had written steps to reproduce, something like that: 1. `vim -u NONE /path/to/file_with_macro` 2. `22ggV"+y` to visually select and copy it to system clipboard. 3. `vim -u NONE` to start a new vim. 4. `"+p` to paste it into a new buffer. Result: `<80><fc>^B...`, expected `Setup`. And post a file with macro, maybe it already has this characters there.

Comment: @ZyX, sorry, you are right. I'm going to delete this question. Perhaps when I get more proficient with vim, I'll someday figure it out. Thank you for the time taken looking into it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using the -W option of vim ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981535/using-the-w-option-of-vim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the gui with `-W` option? Then read [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981535/using-the-w-option-of-vim). It is really related to it.

Comment: I didn't look too closely at this question earlier, looking more closely, it's the same codes, so it probably is that issue again.

Comment: @Chris - that seams very plausible. Apparently the SHIFT+SPACEBAR is a shortcut to adjust the selection of a dialog box.