# How to automate editing of several files in Vim?

Tags: vim, sh

I have a multitude of files in each of which I want to, say, delete lines 1 through 55, add a comment leader (e.g., `//`) on lines 25 through 35, and then save the changes to a new file.

How can I do this automatically with Vim alone or together with the help of a Bash script?

Comment: You need to use `sed` in the `bash` shell if you want to 'edit' files without opening them.

Comment: `ex` would be a better match than `sed`, `ex` uses the same command set set `vi`.

Answer (score 18):

Despite the fact that using `ed` or `sed` is a common practice **¹**
in such cases, sometimes using Vim is much more convenient. Indeed,
instead of writing an `ed`-like script somewhat blindly, it is often
easier to first perform the desired manipulations with one of the
files *interactively* in Vim:

```
vim -w log.vim file1.txt
```

and then repeat it for the rest of the files:

```
for f in file*.txt; do vim -s log.vim "$f"; done
```

For your example use case, the `log.vim` file will likely have
contents similar to the following:

```
gg55dd:25,35s/^/\/\/ /
:w %_new
:q!
```

Note that to save a file with a new name you should not type
it directly, but rather use the `%` substitution, as shown
above—otherwise all the modifications of the subsequent files
will be saved to the same file, overwriting its contents every
time. Alternatively, you can duplicate the files beforehand and
then edit the copies in place (saving each of them simply by
issuing the `:w` command without arguments).

The advantage of this approach is that you can make all of the changes
interactively, ensuring that you are getting the intended result at
least on one of the files, before the edits are performed for the rest
of them.

---

**¹** Of course, you can use Vim in an `ed`-like fashion, too:

```
for f in file*.txt; do vim -c '1,55d|25,35s/^/\/\/ /|w!%_new|q!' "$f"; done
```

Comment: Never do that with the GUI version (gvim), see [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981535/using-the-w-option-of-vim) and the related bug. With the GUI you must edit the scriptout.

Comment: @Benoit Thanks for the warning!  Since I never use GVim, it's unlikely that I could ever notice that behavior, while it's important to know.

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this elegantly with [ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)), the unix line editor, the ancestor of vi.

```
fix_file () {
  ed -s "$1" <<-'EOF'
    1,55d
    25,35s_.*_// &_
    wq   
EOF
}
```

Now, for each file F you need, just execute `fix_file F`.