# How to apply regex commands in vi without opening a file

Tags: bash, vim, editor, vi

I have a set of multiple files requiring the same set of edits, I am trying to create a bash script for editing them in vi, however I don't know how to use vi within the scripts to make the edits? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Instead of `vi` you can use `sed`. You can use `sed` inside the scripts.

Comment: can you specify what's your `same set of edits`?

Comment: I am sorry I should rephrase, I want to apply a recorded set of sequential commands(using qq) on around 100 files

Comment: @sat Thank you for the sed suggestion, I'll be using that. Though I wonder if vi could be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd highly recommend using [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html) or [`awk`](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Awk.html), both programs use regular expressions for selecting and processing text.

*But here's how you can do it using vim too:*

Vim has an `ex` mode (aka commandline version) which solves this purpose and is much easier to use in scripts. Taking the solution from this [answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978224)

You could simply include the following in your bashscript:

```
ex $yourfile <<EOEX
  :%s/$string_to_replace/$string_to_replace_it_with/g
  :x
EOEX
```

For example:

```
ex file.txt << EOEX
  :%s/hello/world/g
  :x
EOEX
```

Or you can use the `-c` option to pass `ex` commands to vim. 
For example:

```
vim file.txt -c ':%s/hello/world/g' -c 'wq'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do a single `:s` command, then you may we well use sed, or you can use `vim -c` as @fnatic_shank suggests.  For more complex scripts, you can use `-S script.vim` instead of several `-c` arguments.  I like to use

```
$ vim -e -s -N -V0vim.log -S script.vim infile.txt
```

See the help for `-N`, `-V`, `-S`, and especially

```
:help -s-ex
```

which includes the warning

> If Vim appears to be stuck try typing "qa!".  You don't
>   get a prompt thus you can't see Vim is waiting for you to type
>   something.

(I ran into this while testing my answer.  I kept infile.txt open in vim, so it asked what to do about the existing swap file when I tried to start a new vim as above.)  If you want to send the file to stdout, then you might have these two lines at the end of script.vim:

```
g/^
silent q!
```