# Using Vim search and replace from within a Bash script

Tags: bash, vim, replace

I have a number of files (more than a hundred) that I want to process using Vim. A sample of the files’ contents is as follows:

```
xyz.csv        /home/user/mydocs/abc.txt

/home/user/waves/wav.wav , user_wav.wav
```

I want this to be replaced by:

```
xyz.csv      /var/lib/mydir/abc.txt
/var/sounds/wav.wav , wav.wav
```

In each of the files, the changes I need to make are the same. My questions are:

1. Can I use Vim search and replace functionality by calling it from within a Bash script?
2. If so, how do I go about it?

**P.S.** I have searched StackOverflow for similar questions and found some answers using `ex` scripts, etc. I want to know how I can call an `ex` script from within a `bash` script.

Comment: I would use a sed instead of what you're trying to do with vim

Comment: See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932102/automated-edit-of-several-files/5932840#5932840) to similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932102/automated-edit-of-several-files).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While vim is quite powerful, this is not something I would normally use vim for. It can be done using a combination of common command line utilities instead.

I've assumed that the blank line in your example above is actually blank and does not contain spaces or any other whitespace characters. You can use the following to do what you want.

```
sed  -e "s,/home/user/mydocs,/var/lib/mydir," -e "s,/home/user/waves,/var/sounds," -e "/^$/d" file1
```

You can use that command together with `find` and a for loop to do this for a bunch of files:

```
for file in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`
do
    sed  -e "s,/home/user/mydocs,/var/lib/mydir," -e "s,/home/user/waves,/var/sounds," -e "/^$/d" $file
done
```

In the for loop, the find command above limits the output to all files in the current directory (including dot files), assigning each line from the output of find to the `file` variable and then running the `sed` command posted earlier to transform the file the way you want it to be transformed.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you'd invoke an `ed` script from bash:

```
ed filename <<END
/^$/d
%s|/home/user/mydocs|/var/lib/mydir|
%s|/home/user/waves|/var/sounds|
%s|, user_|, |
w
q
END
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer with `vim`, you can do

```
vim -e 'bufdo!%s:\(xyz.csv        \)/home/user/mydocs/\(abc.txt\n\)\n.*:\1/var/lib/mydir/\2/var/sounds/wav.wav , wav.wav:' -e 'xa' FILES
```

***Note***, I had assumed, that the second line is statically replaced, as it had looked like in the question.

If you don't like writing long lines in your script, you can create a file like:

```
s/FOO/BAR/
" several replacement and other commands
w " write the file
bd " if you want to
```

Then do:

```
vim -e "buffdo!source /your_scriptfile" -e "x" FILES
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

If all the editing consists in a series of substitutions, the most
idiomatic way of accomplishing it using Vim would be the following.

1. Open all the target files at once:

   ```
    vim *.txt
   ```
2. Run the substitution commands on the loaded files:

   ```
    :argdo %s#/home/user/mydocs#/var/lib/mydir#
    :argdo %s#/home/user/waves#/var/sounds#
    :argdo %s#, \zsuser_##
    ...
   ```
3. If changes are correctly made, save the files:

   ```
   :wall
   ```

If the editing you want to automate could not be expressed only
in substitutions, record a macro and run it via the `:normal`
command:

```
:argdo norm!@z
```

(Here `z` is the name of the macro to be run.)

Lastly, if the editing should be performed from time to time and
needs to be stored in a script, try using the approach described
in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932102/automated-edit-of-several-files/5932840#5932840) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932102/automated-edit-of-several-files).

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

While most vim users would be aware of the % motion command for executing inclusive commands on the whole document in the current buffer. Most modern versions of vim (ie 6.x+) support actions on regex searches for exclusive actions like so:

```
:/regex/substitute/match/replace/ # as vim command line
+"/reges/s/match/replace"         # as bash cli parameter
```

This breaks down into vim doing the following,

1. search for regex and put the cursor at start of found point
2. call internal substitute function (see :help s or :help substitute) [ could be other commands ]
3. match string with regex for substitution
4. replace with new string value

Effectively it operates the same as the :global command.

### Notes

Command after regex search can be any command, including '!"shell command"' filter commands.

### Reference Help

- :help global
- :help substitute
- :help filter