# Vim commands log

Tags: linux, vim, keylogger

Is it possible to log all commands I type in VIM for later analyzing? I mean each simple command like motions or changing the text, i.e. `jjjjjjkkkcw<newword>`

If it is not possible in VIM, maybe there is a keylogger on linux, which can be attached to specific window/process?

I'd prefer in-vim logging, because it could have options to have different logs for different vim modes. Also I don't want to log "colon" commands.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928070/vim-show-my-last-command-command

Comment: i'm in the process of applying a patch to vim73, looking promising

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is! When launching vim use `vim -W ~/vimcommands.log` to >> to a file, or `-w` to overwrite the file.

> -w {scriptout}
>   All the characters that you type are recorded in the file {scriptout}, until you exit Vim. 
>   This is useful if you want to create a script file to be used with "vim -s" or ":source!".
>   If the {scriptout} file exists, characters are appended.
>   -W {scriptout}
>   Like -w, but an existing file is overwritten.

You may want to add a bash alias to store vim logs based on file name.  I am interested to see how you intend to analyse your logs, I would like to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just start recording a macro (`qa` for example will start recording a macro in `a`), and it will record them all for you?

```
Ctrl-R a
```

in insert mode will let you view its contents.

Comment: I'd like to collect statistics of my vim usage during a day (or even a week or month). And I can forget to start recording a macro :). Also I'm using macros sometimes, and I can forget to re-start recording. But I like the idea - will give it a try.

Comment: @cutalion - "statistics of your vim usage during a day" ? For what purpose? Sorry, I think a keylogger in that case will be your only viable alternative.

Comment: @cutalion Macros record into a register, so `:reg a` will print the macro a on the screen, and `"ap` will paste it into the document etc.