# Execute a command within Vim from the command line

Tags: vim

Is there a way to execute a Vim command on a file from the command line?

I know the opposite is true like this:

```
:!python %
```

But what if I wanted to `:retab` a file without opening it in Vim? For example:

```
> vim myfile.c
:retab | wq
```

This will open myfile.c, replace the tabs with spaces, and then save and close. I'd like to chain this sequence together to a single command somehow.

It would be something like this:

```
> vim myfile.c retab | wq
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This works:

```
gvim -c "set et|retab|wq" foo.txt
```

`set et` (= `set expandtab`) ensures the `tab` characters get replaced with the correct number of spaces (otherwise, `retab` won't work).

I don't normally use it, but `vim -c ...` also works

The solution as given above presumes the default tab stop of eight is appropriate. If, say, a tab stop of four is intended, use the command sequence `"set ts=4|set et|retab|wq"`.

Comment: I tried to run this on multiple files using `xargs` (`find -name \*.[ch] | xargs -n 1 vim -c "set et|retab|wq"`), but that was really slow. On each invocation, vim would complain that input was not from a terminal and I think it delays for a second or two to allow reading the message. Alternatively, a for loop leaves stdin untouched and so is fast: `for f in $(find -name \*.[ch]); do vim -c "set et|retab|wq" $f; done`. This is not perfect, though, e.g. filenames with spaces or too many filenames break this (so maybe vim has an option to suppress that warning).

Answer (score 59):

You have several options:

- `-c "commands"` : will play Ex commands as you entered them in the command line.
   In your example : `vim myfile -c 'retab | wq'`. This is what Firstrock suggested.
- `-S "vim source file"` : will source given vim script
  (like running `vim -c "source 'vim source file'"`):

  If you have a file `script.vim` containing:

  ```
  retab
  wq
  ```

  Then you can use `vim myfile.c -s script.vim` (the extension does not really matter)
- `-s "scriptin file"`: will play contents of file as it contains **normal mode** commands: If you have `script.txt` containing:

  ```
  :retab
  ZZ
  ```

  *with end of lines consisting of a single `^M` character* (for example you saved the script using the `:set fileformat=mac | w`), then you can run: `vim myfile.c -S script.txt` (`ZZ` is another way to exit vim and save current file).
  Note that you can record those scripts with `vim my_file -W script.txt`, but it [suffers a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981535/using-the-w-option-of-vim) if you happen to use gvim (the GUI).

Comment: If you, like me, just want to execute a handful of commands, in some shells you can use `vim -S <(echo -e "VundleInstall \n q \n q")`.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you want to replace tabs with spaces (or do any other regex search/replace) for a list of files, you can just use in-place sed search/replace:

```
sed -i 's/\t/   /g' foo1.txt foo2.txt
```

or

```
ls *.txt | xargs sed -i 's/\t/   /g'
```

(In this example I am replacing each tab character with three spaces.)

---

NOTE: the `-i` flag means operate in-place.

From the `sed` man page:

```
   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

          edit files in place (makes backup if  extension
          supplied)
```

Comment: You're right - one shouldn't use the microscope like a can opener

Comment: In my experience if the file is huge (order of 100s of MB) and the number of replacements are limited, then sed is painfully slow. The 'vim -s <script_file>' option suggested by @benoit works much faster - order of seconds. In my case, sed took about 3 minutes, while the vim script option completed in about 25 sec for a file 200 MB large and about 100 replacements