# Use vim as command line tool?

Tags: linux, vim, indentation

is there a way to use vim as a command line tool? What I mean is, use it from the console (without opening a ncurses window) to run vim commands on file and save them. I need this because I usually run through all my files and do 'gg=G' to auto indent them.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218528/indenting-in-vim-with-all-the-files-in-folder may help you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366243/execute-a-command-within-vim-from-the-command-line.

Comment: `:bufdo` may help -- if have a bunch of files opened in a vim session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-vim-script-in-a-non-interactive-mode) are listed two different ways to do that:

- by using `vim -s file-containing-commands file-to-edit`
- by using `vim file "+:firstcommand" "+:secondcommand" ...`

The first solution needs a file to be written beforehands; the second solution will launch vim and execute the commands, without leaving vim; you'll have to do that yourself, for instance adding a last  command `'+:x'`

Comment: That's good for regular commands, but I needed to run gg=G on everything! This was my solution using your suggestion `vim file.c '+execute "normal gg=G"' +wq`. This is going straight to my bin folder ;).