# How can I use vim in a pipeline to colorize text?

Tags: vim, command-line

I'd like to have a command I can insert into a command pipeline that adds color escapes to its input according to vim's syntax highlighting capabilities.

For example:

```
cat somefile.js | vim - <???> | less
```

The resulting text would be that of somefile.js, but colorized according to how the current vim configuration would do it in-editor.

It occurs to me that this **must** be possible.  I agree that the example up there isn't what a sane man might call exactly *useful*, but that doesn't mean the idea *never* is.

Comment: There is a wide variety of software that does this, pygmentize is one. I've never seen vim do it.

Comment: Hrm.. [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219479/vim-write-buffer-content-to-stdout), though lowly rated, seems to suggest trying to use vim as a filter at all (essentially what I'm looking for here), is just a bad idea from the get-go.  Is that true?  Is this idea just a non-starter?

Comment: +1 for out-of-the-box thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your idea has one basic flaw: that nobody ever thought about allowing such a thing.

Clearly vim is capable of doing syntax highlighting.  But I'll bet you an ice cream cone that if you can manage to get vim to stream text through and process it, that you won't like the results.

Consider what happens when you pipe text through `more` (or `less` if you prefer).  When it goes to the terminal, these programs display one screenful and wait for you to hit the space bar.  But if you redirect stdout to some other place than the terminal, these programs notice this and simply copy their input to their output unchanged.

If vim doesn't notice that you are piping text through, it is likely to send cursor-movement commands that you probably don't want in your output.  If vim does notice, it is likely to just pass the text, and not syntax-color it.  Only if vim does do the syntax-coloring but does not inject cursor-movement stuff will your idea work.

You could try it.  Here's an answer that discusses piping stuff through vim:

[Execute a command within Vim from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366243/execute-a-command-within-vim-from-the-command-line)

But I say why not pipe your text through a program that was designed and intended to have text piped through it?  Pygments can colorize every major programming language and markup format.

http://pygments.org/

The major advantage I see for your idea: you can customize the way vim does syntax coloring, get it the way you want it, and then also use vim to process your text.  But it's probably not that hard to customize Pygments, and it might even be satisfactory out of the box, in which case it would definitely be the easiest way to go.  And Pygments not only has ANSI sequence output, it also has HTML output, RTF, LaTeX, etc.  So if you get Pygments working the way you want it to, it should be able to output whatever output format you need; vim will only have the ANSI sequence one.

Comment: You're right -- vim isn't designed as a filter, so use something that is.  You're also right that the main motivator here is to colorize text the way I've set up *vim* to do so.  But that's hardly a critical need -- I just *wanna*.  :)  I'll check out Pygments.  Thanks for the recommendation.  And thanks for a good explanation as to why I wasn't getting far with my approach.  Cheers.

Comment: Okay, pygmentize is pretty damn cool.  I wish it had better lexer auto-detection, but then I could use a project..

Answer (score 3):

There's a Perl module called Text::VimColor that I've heard will do kinda what you're looking for.

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-VimColor/

But let me ask this: Why do want it to go through less?  Why not use vim as a perfectly good file viewer?  `view -` will read from standard input in read-only mode.

Comment: The idea is not that it go specifically through `less`, but that I can have something that applies syntax highlighting to text in such a way that I can process it further on the command line.  Like, say, if I want to do `cat file.js | grep function | <something>`, it helps if <something> shows me highlighting, for easier readability.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `vimcat` !

```sh
wget -O /usr/local/bin/vimcat "https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=23422"
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/vimcat
vimcat /etc/passwd
```

See also: https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4325

Comment: Perfect, works exactly as I want (upvote from me)

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/echristopherson/4090959

Via https://superuser.com/a/554531/7198.

Tried on `/etc/passwd` and it works surprisingly well!

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're after

```
cat filename.sh | vim - -c 'syntax on; syn=bash'
```

This is ugly, but you could alias this:

```
alias vim.sh="vim -c 'syntax on; syn=bash'"
```

Then use like this:

```
cat filename.sh | vim.sh -
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it just opens `vim` as usual. FWIW, I am not quire sure which part in your code supposed to make vim exit. The `-` makes it read from stdin, and `-c syntax on; syn=bash` seems to just enable syntax highlight.