# How to know commands I've been typing?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm using gVim and I would like to know if there is a way to see the commands I've been typing.

For example, when I pressed the visual mode (<kbd>v</kbd>) I've got message `-- Visual --`, but I don't know which letters I've been pressing so far.

Is there a way to permanent see which characters/commands I've typing?

Answer (score 19):

You can use this setting:

```
:set showcmd
```

Type `:help 'showcmd'` to read more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it isn't working. I used `:set showcmd` as you suggested but when i enter into the visual mode is not showing the letters i pressed, only appears the `--Visual --` tag.

Comment: Well, i'm using `viw`, that select the inner word in visual mode. And i want to see what i'm typing. I can't believe Vi/Vim haven't something for this. :(

Comment: After you `:set showcmd` When you type `vi` it will show on the lower right of the screen. When you type `w` it will all disappear.

Comment: NOTE: This can be slow over SSH just like "set relativenumber" can.

Answer (score 2):

You could set this up:

```bash
alias vim="vim -W ~/.last_vim_session_key_pressed"
```

But this file is written only when you exit vim. You can source it with `vim -s` but beware, with vim gui versions you can have [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981535/using-the-w-option-of-vim).

Answer (score 1):

Check your home directory for a `.viminfo` file.

This will have, among other things, a history from newest to oldest of recent commands you've typed.

Comment: Could it be but not exactly what i want. I dont want to check history or any info related to the last command typed. Would like to see the command in a more interactive way: while i'm pressing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tricky way to show all vim keystrokes which were pressed by using `-w` parameter which record all the characters that you type in the file. The problem is, that vim writes keystrokes only when you exit Vim as [Benoit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457352/benoit) already said.

To workaround this, [Kana Natsuno](https://github.com/kana) came up with this [single-line patch](https://gist.github.com/kana/4202311), which disables buffering of the `-w` option, so you have access to realtime stream of keystrokes. Then it's a matter of reading them (e.g. `tail -f`), parsing or you can try to display them in the statusbar (`:set statusline`).

Check out a custom build of Vim using Drew's [live-stream-keystrokes branch](https://github.com/nelstrom/macvim/commit/c65e7e650b806682152681c58078d29cb1904bfe) of MacVim, to get the realtime stream of keystrokes.

Source: [Vimprint - a Vim keystroke parser](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/05/vimprint---a-vim-keystroke-parser/) at Drew Neil blog

This is useful if you'd like to reveal the Vim pressed keystrokes in live video tutorials (or GIFs).